# Asymptotic distribution of portfolio weights in R

Tags: r, statistics, mathematical-optimization, portfolio

I obtained a minimum-risk frontier by minimizing covariance of the asset returns (risk measure). This is known as the modern portfolio theory which was proposed by Harry Markowitz in 1952. Now I want to obtain a confidence interval for the portfolio weights of the Global Minimum Variance(GMV) portfolio. I need to find the asymptotic distribution of the GMV portfolio weights.

How can I do that in R/Python? I am using fPortfolio package in R.

Comment: Not sure about the GMV, but the `MarkowitzR` package can find the variance-covariance of the Markowitz Portfolio; see also "Asymptotic Distribution of the Markowitz Portfolio" by Pav on arxiv 2013. The GMV probably has a similar distribution, which you could compute with automatic differentiation and the delta-method.